# How to configure tomcat7 to deliver markdown files?

Tags: tomcat7, markdown

I have a markdown file that I would like to have delivered by my tomcat 7. Currently when calling the url of the file, it offers me the file to download. But I want to have it just rendered. I have a plugin in the browser to convert md files into html, so I don't care if I just see the md "source code".

If there is even an md => html converter plugin for Tomcat, even better. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: It might be worth writing a small servlet app, to deliver the file *as* a *.txt* file. These are rendered *as is* and aren't interpreted by the browser.

Comment: In the end I want to use this with the continuous integration server Jenkins and just publish my md files. Writing a servlet for this wouldn't be that easy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at what your browser is doing with that file. A quick test on a clean Tomcat installation with a file named test.md displays the contents of that file in the browser (FireFox).

If the browser is expecting a particular MIME type, then you can configure that in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml (look for the very long section setting MIME mappings).